# Which folders from /home should I move to a SSD?

Tags: linux, firefox, ssd

I recently bought an 128GB SSD for my laptop. After moving everything in `/` to the SSD I still have 95GB left on it. Now I was thinking about moving some of the content of `/home/`  to the SSD.
As far as I know there are two things to consider

- the speedup gained by moving a file/folder to the SSD drive
- how much the writes to a file will wear down the drive

things that I have considered moving are

- the `.config` folder
- my firefox profile (including cache)
- my thunderbird profile
- some VMs
- PyCharm's config files

Which folders are best suited for being moved? (considering speed and wear)

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question has no specific answer - it depends on the user and what sort of things you use your machine for. It is VERY opinion based

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a similar thing. I moved my entire /home to the SSD (40GB), but used bind mount to mount specific folders under ~ to the old HDD home (500GB)  (now under /usr/local/storage/home, this is where I also keep other big storages for audio, video, pictures), especially the Download and Documents folder, and some code stuff, that is quite large and doesn’t change often.

The old HDD /home now is the same as before, but has gained also a bit of space, since a lot of stuff has been moved to the SSD.

P.S. you could use symbolic link to the the same without bind mount, but I like the other solution better, as it better hides the fact that these are on a different partition/file system.